# Passport-jwt issue : JWT token is working with postman but not working with UI api call

Tags: jwt, passport.js

I have integrated passport-jwt for authentication purpose. It's working like charm but whenever Frontend guy use it from frontend  angular 2 its giving Unauthorised 401 . I've tried alot but not getting any clue, it must be a silly mistake though.

**my passport strategy file is as**

```
let JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
//let fromHeader = require('passport-jwt').fromHeader


// load up the user model
const User = require('../components/user/model');
const database = require('./database'); // get db config file
const config = require('./config'); // get db config file

module.exports = function(passport) {
//var passportStrategy = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  //opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("JWT");

  console.log("opts.jwtFromRequest==",opts.jwtFromRequest);

  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;//config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    //console.log("opt==",JSON.stringify(opt));
    //console.log("jwt_payload===",jwt_payload);
    User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function(err, user) {

          if (err) {
              return done(err, false);
          }
          if (user) {
              done(null, user);
          } else {
              done(null, false);
          }
      });
  }));
};
```

**my route is as**

```
app.get("/api/user/getAll",
    passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),
    userController.fetchUsers
);
```

**And frontend header append is as follows :**

```
logoutUser(token) {

//const userData = JSON.stringify(userInfo);

var headers = new Headers();


headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

headers.append('Authorization', token); //e.g.token = JWT dasddddasdsda 

//headers.append('Authentication', token);

console.log(headers)



return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/user/logout', { headers: headers })

.map((response: Response) =〉 {

return response.json()

})

.catch(this.errorHandler);

}
```

It would really great if anyone can assist me further to identify the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument for the post method is payload.

so this code below

`this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/user/logout', { headers: headers })`
 
has to be

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/user/logout', {}, { headers: headers })
```